# Am I using the word paradox right?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a short bit on time travel just to get my thoughts on paper and try to organize them, and need to make sure I'm using the word paradox right. Here's the quote I'm concerned about right now-

> If you change the past, you will most likely remove the event that required you to change the past.  If this happens and you do not change the past because the event that triggered you changing the past is no longer there, it becomes a paradox and who knows what happens now.

Google said it was a contradictory phrase to itself, which I think lets it work in this situation. If there's a better word I'm missing, let me know. This is not for school or anything, just some notes I'm writing for myself.

Comment: "contradictory phrase to itself" That should be "phrase contradictory to itself".

Comment: The fun comes when you come up with an exception to make the paradox work - like changing the past results in a new universe being formed, or that the past is actually a separate reality to ours and time is multidimensional. You aren't killing your own grandfather and preventing your birth, but someone identical to your grandfather in another previously identical universe. Fun stuff!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you're using it right. The concept you describe is called the [grandfather paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox) and features in a lot of time-travel stories.